# Why was the equals() method in java.util.Comparator made abstract?

Tags: java

Why was the `equals()` method in `java.util.Comparator` made abstract, if it is already implemented in the `Object` class?

Comment: This is a real, legitimate question and should not have been closed.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's worth noting that the method is not "made abstract". If you implement `Comparator<T>` without implementing `equals()`, your code *will* compile. Your class will simply use the implementation provided by `Object`.

As to why re-declare the method, this is done because the contract on `Comparator<T>.equals()` is more stringent than the contract on `Object.equals()`. This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Additionally, this method can return true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator. Thus, comp1.equals(comp2) implies that sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2)) for every object reference o1 and o2.

If `Comparator` did not override `equals()`, there would be no good way to specify that its contract on `equals()` is different from `Object`'s.

Comment: You could even use stronger wording: it's about the *contract*, not just documentation, and the interface is the artifact that specifies the contract.